# "English to Pirate" text translator. I need a button that resets the page and clears the translated text

Tags: html

This is what I have to work with so far:

```
<html>
<body>
 <h3>Land Lubber's Pirate Translator</h3>
 <p>Simply click on the buttons to translate
 words and/or phrases from English to pirate talk.
 </p>
 <p>
 <input type="button" value="hello"
 onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
 document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + 'ahoy ';">
 <input type="button" value="stranger"
 onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML =
 document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + 'scurvy dog ';">
 </p>
 <hr>
 <div id="outputDiv"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

As the page is currently written, multiple translations are awkward. If you finish translating one phrase and want to begin a new one, you must reload the page to clear the page division. To make repeated translations easier, add a button labeled "Clear the Translation" below the word/phrase buttons. When the user clicks on this button, the contents of the page division should be cleared (**by assigning its INNERHTML attribute to be the empty string**).

I'm not understanding what the bolded part means for me to do?

Comment: An empty string is simply `''` or `""`, depending on which you prefer. Everything else is the same as the code you already have in the other buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You have already been changing the innerHTML attribute of your output div to add your translations. What you are being asked to do is to set the innerHTML of your output to be `""` (or `''`). This clears all output because `""` is an empty string. So, you need to add another button with an onclick attribute that sets innerHTML to `""`. To do this, you need to add the code shown below.

```
<input type="button" value="Clear the Translation" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = ''">
```

```html
<h3>Land Lubber's Pirate Translator</h3>
<p>Simply click on the buttons to translate words and/or phrases from English to pirate talk.
</p>

<p>

  <input type="button" value="hello" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + 'ahoy';">
  <input type="button" value="stranger" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + 'scurvy dog';">

  <!-- ADD CODE HERE -->
  <input type="button" value="Clear the Translation" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = ''">

</p>

<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h3>Land Lubber's Pirate Translator</h3>
  <p>Simply click on the buttons to translate words and/or phrases from English to pirate talk.
  </p>
  <form action="#">
    <input type="button" value="hello" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
 document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + 'ahoy ';">
    <input type="button" value="stranger" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML =
 document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + 'scurvy dog ';">
    <input type="button" value="Clear the Translation" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = '';">
  </form>
  <hr>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```